# how to combine combine two foreach loops into one

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my code so far now i want to combine this what i can do ?

```
<table>
            <tr>

                <th>Imported Files</th> 
                <th>Report Files</th> 
            </tr>
<?php

    $dir = str_replace("/var/www/13_Feb/subscriber-files/","","/var/www/13_Feb/subscriber-files/u*.[cC][sS][vV]");
    $dir2 = str_replace("/var/www/13_Feb/subscriber-files/","","/var/www/13_Feb/subscriber-files/r*.[cC][sS][vV]");



    foreach(glob($dir) as $file)  {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>". $file."</td>";
            }

            foreach(glob($dir2) as $file)  {
            echo "<td>". $file."</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";

?>
</table>
```

I want to print like this

```
            echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $file1."</td>";
    echo "<td>". $file2."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
```

i.e in the same td what I can do Help me

```
update:-
```

I want to print this in to td

```
$dir = str_replace("/var/www/13_Feb/subscriber-files/","","/var/www/13_Feb/subscriber-files/u*.[cC][sS][vV]");
$dir2 = str_replace("/var/www/13_Feb/subscriber-files/","","/var/www/13_Feb/subscriber-files/r*.[cC][sS][vV]");
```

Comment: do you have the same number of files in each directory? Are you saying you want to show the first file in dir next to the first file in dir2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one handles files lists of different sizes.

Plus, you can have more than two columns of "file lists" displayed in the same table.

```
// retrieve data

$dirs = array(glob($dir), glob($dir2));

// display

$max_files = max(array_map('count', $dirs));
$count_dirs = count($dirs);

echo '<table>';

for($i = 0; $i < $max_files; $i++)
{
  echo '<tr>';
  for($d = 0; $d < $count_dirs; $d++)
  {
    $strFile = (isset($dirs[$d][$i]) ? $dirs[$d][$i] : '[NO FILE]');
    echo '<td>'.$strFile.'</td>';
  }
  echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: And? What am I supposed to do with that?

Comment: :) your code is works fine for me in any test page but actually not working with zend when i replace str_replace after that it also works in zend what i can do any suggestion???????????

Comment: Why don't you simply add `chdir("/var/www/13_Feb/subscriber-files");` before the processing? Then you can do `$dir = 'u*.[cC][sS][vV]';` etc., and after that, the `glob()` calls... BTW if you're satisfied with my answer, please don't forget to accept/upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$line .= "<tr>";
foreach(glob($dir) as $file)  {     
    $line .= "<td>". $file."</td>";
}
foreach(glob($dir2) as $file)  {
    $line .= "<td>". $file."</td>";
}
$line .= "</tr>";

echo $line;
```

Answer (score 0):

If they should be combined and both are of the same size, perhaps this will be a solution (untested)

```
$dir1_files = glob($dir);
$dir2_files = glob($dir2);

for ($i =0; $i < count($dir1_files); $i++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    printf("<td>%s</td>", $dir1_files[$i]);
    printf("<td>%s</td>", $dir2_files[$i]);
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.3+ has a [`MultipleIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php) for this, combined with the [`GlobIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.globiterator.php) you can have a solution like this:

```
$iterator = new MultipleIterator();
$iterator->attachIterator(new GlobIterator($dir);
$iterator->attachIterator(new GlobIterator($dir2);
foreach ($iterator as $current) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $current[0] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>". $current[1] ."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

If you have a different number of files and want to display all of them, you can use the `MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ANY` Flag:

```
$iterator = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ANY);
$iterator->attachIterator(new GlobIterator($dir);
$iterator->attachIterator(new GlobIterator($dir2);
foreach ($iterator as $current) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". (isset($current[0]) ? $current[0] : '&nbsp;') ."</td>";
    echo "<td>". (isset($current[1]) ? $current[1] : '&nbsp;') ."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```